# "It’s not perfectly clear to me what it is you’re trying to say" vs. "It’s not perfectly clear to me what you’re trying to say"

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. It’s not perfectly clear to me what ***it is*** you’re trying to say.
> 2. It’s not perfectly clear to me what you’re trying to say.

Supposing (2) is grammatical, what, if any, is the difference between it and (1)?

Anyway, is (2) good English?

Comment: I (non-native) use [2] all the time in casual conversations. [1] has the same meaning but it gives me a bit more tense and formal feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both seem fine to me.  I detect no difference in meaning.

I personally think the first sentence sounds better, so I think I'd be more likely to say that one.  Some people prefer to say things with fewer words when possible, so I suppose they might prefer the second.  But you can use either one, really.